# Django framework startapp

Tags: python, django

Followed by tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-debian-8

I have installed Django on virtualenv and when i want to startapp i have following error:

```
(myprojectenv) pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ ls
db.sqlite3  manage.py  myproject  myprojectenv  static
(myprojectenv) pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ python manage.py startapp blog
CommandError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pi/myproject/blog'
```

When trying type "sudo" before the command i got error like this:

```
(myprojectenv) pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ sudo python manage.py startapp blog
  File "manage.py", line 14
) from exc
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: is this problem occurs if you run the command without sudo?

Comment: Your virtualenv uses Python 2. Newer Django versions only support Python 3.

Comment: (myprojectenv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python -V
Python 3.5.3

Comment: Maybe is problem with permission to create a folder "blog" on my '/home/pi/myproject/blog' directory, so how to get permission to this folder to create other folders inside? i have set chmod 755 on '/home/pi/myproject" directory.